# Userform If statement for specific selected items from Listbox using a command button

Tags: vba, button, userform, selected

So what I'm trying to do.... I have a command button that I want to target specific selected items from a Listbox and subsequently run a sub procedure for each item.

I have the following code which doesn't run, but just to give an idea.

Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

```
For i = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
If ListBox2.Selected(i) = "Gr BO" Then
    Call GR_BO
If ListBox2.Selected(i) = "Ref BO" Then
    Call Ref_BO
End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this I used .List(I) instead of .selected(I) and it worked as designed. Not entirely sure why .selected wouldn't work (type mismatch - 13 error), however, for what I needed I did not need to limit to selected items